# correct way to pass parameter to ajax request

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am trying to pass string to service using Ajax. But i get error `unexpected token illegal`

```
function main() {
    age =  <%= myclass._age %>;
    passedname = encodeURIComponent( <%= myclass._namestrings %> );
    $.ajax({
        url: 'https://myservice/index.json',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: "searchstring=" + passedname + "&take=" + age + "",
        success: function (data) {
            var first = true;
            $("#dataDiv").html("");
            $.each(data, function (index, record) {
                var html = "";

                $.each(record, function (index1, data) {
                   html += data.name;

                });
                $("#myDiv").append(html);

            });
        },
        statusCode: {
            404: function () {
                debugger;
                alert('Failed');
            }
        }
    });
}
```

I pass variable passedname as John but it gives error.
If i pass variable passedname as "John" i.e passing double quotes then it Works. I dont want user to pass it in double quotes.

Comment: is this page being rendered by a server? i think the error is because of `<%= myclass._age %>` and `<%= myclass._namestrings %>` Java scriptlets not being rendered or the fact that they are missing quotes `"`. if you view the HTML of the page what do you see in place of the tags? Try writing `"<%= myclass._age %>"` and `"<%= myclass._namestrings %>"` (age probably doesn't need quotes since i suppose it's a number)

Comment: @valepu Thanks it worked with "<%= myclass._namestrings %>"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put quotes between the String values that get replaced server side, in this case you should add quotes between `<%= myclass._namestrings %>`:

```
 passedname = encodeURIComponent( "<%= myclass._namestrings %>" );
```